# error installing 3rd party Packages via npm for angular4

Tags: angular, npm

I have tried to install `angular2-datatable` and `loadash` via

```
npm install --save angular2-datatable
```

and

```
sudo npm i --save lodash
```

but this error

```
reporter-ui@0.0.0 /Users/.../Desktop/reporter-ui
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.2.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.2.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.2.3
└── angular2-datatable@0.6.0 

npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

showed up both times. how do I update these dependencies? if I do a `ng --version`

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 7.10.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.3
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3
```

and I have tried to manually change the versions to the correct ones in my `package.json` but I'm still getting the error. it seems to me that the correct versions are installed, but how do I tell the angular cli and or npm that? Also, I have tried upgrading npm and the angular cli still the same error.

Comment: Those look more like warnings that can be ignored. Is your code running afterward? If yes, then move on.

Comment: I am having such errors in my react build. They do not interfere with my build and seem to be irrelevant for now.

Comment: You need to ignore those warnings. That won't affect your coding. So just more ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Further investigation, the error that was being generated was unrelated to the stated warnings. as stated by the comments, these warnings can be ignored, everything is working as expected.